# Does MongoDB ignore calling Reduce function when Map emits one result?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, nosql

I notice that when the Map function returns one entry, then Reduce doesn't get called.

1. Is this the default behaviour?
2. Can MongoDB be forced to always call the Reduce function?

Comment: Looking through other SO questions, this is default behavior. I got around this by using the aggregation framework in MongoDB v2.2

Comment: @JonathanOng, what is your feeling about the 2.2 rc? does it feel stable?

Comment: well i haven't used it for production, but no problems I know of so far. But then again I don't do anything crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently MongoDB develipers decided to optimize MapReduce queries by ignoring Reduce function for unique keys as explained [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2333).